# how to align image and text when floating to image

Tags: html, css

how to make as below when using `display: inline-block;`

```
+----------+  heading text here
|  image   +  some paragraph text
+----------+

+----------+  heading text here
|  image   +  some paragraph text
+----------+
```

hmtl I used...

```
<div class="videos">
  <div><img src=""><h3>heading text here</h3><p>some paragraph text</p></div>
  <div><img src=""><h3>heading text here</h3><p>some paragraph text</p></div>
</div>
```

css I used...

```
.videos{
  display: inline-block; /* i have to use this as other elements to be inline-block */
}
.videos img{
  float: left;
}
```

Solution for my problem is that "some paragraph text" should not go below image.
Or any method to get that?

**Edit**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pJWBH/)** why the second heading and text going to right even after setting `text-align: left !imortant;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your `h3` and `p` inside a div:

```
<div class="right">
    <h3>heading text here</h3><p>some paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

Then you just need to float that div to the right side of the image

```
div.right {
    float: right;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ydDeX/)**

---

The problem happens when a floated element is within a container box, that element does not automatically force the container’s height adjust to the floated element. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow. You can use 2 methods to fix it which is `clear: both` by adding:

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

This is a quick and dirty solution but not encourage to use since it has many disadvantages. The more elegant and correct way is to use `clearfix` which is a technique for an element to automatically clear after itself, so that you don't need to add additional markup. It's generally used in float layouts where elements are floated to be stacked horizontally.

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

You can find alot of resources about `clearfix` on the internet. Here is the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJWBH/1/)** based on your updated question.

Comment: Sidenote just in case: these divs now only contain floats, a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) may be needed

Comment: Remove your feddle as this doesn't have picture included.

Comment: Ok! you have set fright to left. It is working. thanks. but why is it not working when setting it right?

Comment: @Chapurlink I don't get what you means, but maybe because your text's length are different.

Comment: you have set fright{float: left;}, why is it not working when applying float: right;

Comment: It's still works, just because your second paragraph has less text than the others that make you feel it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of having a *column* of content next to a float than using another float is with `overflow: hidden` (*column* meaning if content is taller than the image, it doesn't display under this float)

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kUdBm/

Comment: This is a subtle application of `overflow: hidden` that is often overlooked, but can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that :

```
.video p h3{
  float : right;
 }
```

It should work.

Comment: @Chapurlink Is that what you wanted ? (My english is bad, I wasn't sure)

Comment: .video p, .video h3 but i got another very nice answer, anyway +1 for you okay.

Answer (score 0):

here is demo your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/bartekbielawa/cgWtH/

**CSS CODE**

```
.videos{
  display: inline-block; /
}

.videos div {
    clear: both;
    margin: 20px 0;
    min-height: 60px;
}


.videos img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px; 
  margin-right: 10px;  
}

.videos div h3, videos div p {
    float: left;
}

.videos div h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to put width on the H3 and p you'r using. Otherwise if the h3 and p is big it will be under the image.

Comment: but still goes below to image